# .net core Windows Service Wix install Window service issue : The application to execute does not exist

Tags: .net-core, wix3

I am using *VS 2019* and *.NET Core 3.1*.

I have converted windows service to *.NET Core 3.1* and tried to create the *msi* installer using WIX.

I have created the installer, and while trying to start the application I am getting the error like

`The application to execute does not exist: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\DRAProcessorServiceFolder\Django_DRAProcessorService.dll'`.

My product.wxs code is below

```
<File Id="Django_DRAProcessorService" Name="Django_DRAProcessorService.exe" Source="..\Django_DRAProcessorService\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win10-x64\Django_DRAProcessorService.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" />

        <ServiceInstall
          Id="ServiceInstaller"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Vital="yes"
          Name="WorkingService2"
          DisplayName="Django_DRAProcessorService"
          Description="Django_DRAProcessorService"
          Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
          Start="auto"
          Interactive="no"
          ErrorControl="normal"

            />

        <ServiceControl
            Id="ServiceInstaller"
            Start="install"
            Stop="both"
            Remove="uninstall"
            Name="Django_DRAProcessorService"
            Wait="yes" />
```

If anybody knows any solution please help me.

Comment: Looks like a missing file. Are you sure it's present in the installer?

Comment: Which one is missing , i didnot get that ,

Comment: Django_DRAProcessorService.dll as per the error. Does not exist = missing.

Comment: Finally i am  able to  fix the issue . Thanks